# Enterprise Territory Management: how to remove territory assigned by rule in account

Tags: enterprise, territory

I used Enterprise Territory Management. For the territory model, I set the rules for each territory by geography.
For example:
- Global Sales
  -- San Fransisco (Account Billing State: San Fransisco)
  -- Canada (Account Billing State: Canada)
  -- Santa Clara (Account Billing State: Santa Clara)

When I created account with Billing State:San Fransisco, it will automatically assign that account to territory: San Fransisco.

And it turns out that the salesperson made mistake in inputting the Billing State. The Billing State should be Canada.
How to change the assigned territory here so it will change from territory: San Fransisco to territory: Canada?

Please advice.

Thanks.

Regards,
Silvia